# Display connections externally

Tags: python, terminal, maya

In my rig, say if I have this `main_ctrl` connected to this `main_geo` where its connection is stated as follows:

```
main_ctrl.message -> main_geo.Cache
```

And this rig file is saved as a .ma file.

I was wondering if it is possible, that I can display such connections externally, for example using linux terminal?
I do know that in its file format `.ma`, it is still unable to display the connections other than the geos/ctrls etc used in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few options. Pick your poison:

- [CG Kit](http://cgkit.sourceforge.net) can give you this scene information. I've not used it, before, but give it a shot
- Parse the `.ma` file searching for lines containing `connectAttr` and the name of the object
- Use the `mayabatch` command line tool to run a script which outputs the connections, then read that back in using `subprocess`
- Save important connection data to an external database or companion file while in Maya

Comment: See, this is why I shouldn't try to write answers on my phone on the train before coffee. Too much working against me

Comment: I agree happens to me too... Anyway CG kit works but is a bit unwieldy imho (so i implemented my own) Anyway short names is a problem.

Comment: Yeah, I won't be integrating it into my pipeline any time soon

Comment: Well the reason youd want to read the binary file would be to make windows/Mac/linux file browser and your version control aware of Maya metadata.

Comment: I have an in-house asset manager storing everything in a MySQL database powered by a python API. Checking in scenes is done through that, and all our useful metadata is either dropped into the database or stored in a node to be accessed in-scene.

Comment: Thanks guys. Did try option 2 - parsing the `.ma`, and tried looking for the lines containing `connectAttr`. Though I found a lot of similar lines, I came upon a few that seems to be similar but yet again, I do not think it is stated as the one I have mentioned in my thread. Gonna try if option 3...

Comment: @user3212246 maya will use short names for the attribute names. So it will not read main_ctrl.message fir example but instead read main_ctrl.msg and so on refer to your node manual.